# Query for selecting duplicates + finding lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in 3 different databaes; Currently the goal here is to find the duplicates unique ID in the three databases and then find the lowest price value of the duplicates unique ID.

Currently I'm using a INNER JOIN to query between only 2 database... Can anyone advise on how to add the third one?

```
set @a = (SELECT db1.tb1.var1 from db1.tb1
INNER JOIN db2.tb1 ON db2.tb1.var1 = db1.tb1.var1
UNION  );
```

Also, once I have the `@a` variable set to the duplicate, I wanted to grab a secondary value here.

```
SELECT price
 FROM db1.tb1
  WHERE asin=@a
UNION ALL
SELECT price
 FROM db2.tb1
  WHERE asin=@a
UNION ALL
SELECT  price
 FROM db3.tb1
  WHERE asin=@a
```

However, the result I'd get would return multiple rows (obviously), How do I query only for the MIN() number from this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Put your query into a subquery, and then use `MIN()` in the main query.

```
SELECT MIN(price)
FROM (
    SELECT price
     FROM db1.tb1
      WHERE asin=@a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT price
     FROM db2.tb1
      WHERE asin=@a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  price
     FROM db3.tb1
      WHERE asin=@a) AS x
```

Comment: Hi @barmar,
Does this include exclusions for multiple matching values for the unique identifier ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT price
FROM db1.tb1
WHERE asin = @a
UNION ALL
SELECT price
FROM db2.tb1
WHERE asin = @a
UNION ALL
SELECT price
FROM db3.tb1
WHERE asin = @a
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1;
```